# Bootstrap - span element is not aligned to label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

My form is to be capable of switching between view and edit modes. By default the form should display in view mode and when I click edit button the fields should be available for change. The form is working good between view and edit modes as expected, but in view mode the span element (for display value) is misaligned with the label, I mean the span element's value is displaying a bit higher to the horizontal line of the label.

Below is a piece of code from my form:

```
div class="container">
    <h1>Deal Form</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #dealForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
          <span class="control-label" *ngIf="!editMode">{{model.name}</span>
          <div class="col-sm-6" *ngIf="editMode">
             <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" />
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [form static control](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-controls-static) instead of a `<span>` element:

```
div class="container">
    <h1>Deal Form</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #dealForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6" *ngIf="editMode">
             <p class="form-control-static" *ngIf="!editMode">{{model.name}}</p>
             <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" />
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is a "static" Bootstrap snippet (view in full page):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Deal Form</h1>
  <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #dealForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="model name" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Deal Form</h1>
  <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #dealForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <p class="form-control-static">model name</p>
      </div>     
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now. Thanks for the help. However I have modified the code to meet my requirement and it's as below.

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <p class="form-control-static" *ngIf="!editMode">{{var1}}</p>
                        <input class="form-control"  *ngIf="editMode" type="text" name="var1" [(ngModel)]="var1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```